# Gnucash: How to find transactions of a specific amount?

Tags: gnucash, research, charges

I've got a Gnucash credit card account in which I'd like to find all transactions of a specific amount. The Find window doesn't have the Charge Amount field in it, and I don't see any relevant information in Help. Is this something that I can do in Gnucash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Find window doesn't have the Charge Amount field in it

It's the "Value" field.

[image: Value field]

Comment: Aha! "Value" and "charge amount" don't correspond very closely in my head, so that one never occurred to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As another option, you can go to "View:Sort By..." and choose "Amount".  This should make it easy to find those transactions in the list.

Note that payments will be listed separately from charges, as they are effectively negative and positive amounts.

Comment: A creative solution. I like it.

Comment: This is good for situations where you don't know the exact amount.